# How to Create a String from a StreamReader for Analysis

Tags: c#, string, streamreader

I want to be able to search through a given HTML and find certain tags

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = "http://www.google.com";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

How do I convert what I have from the StreamReader into a String so that I can do further analysis...

Comment: Learn to read the documentation. See [StreamReader class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)

Comment: In fact, take a look at [TextReader class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx). It's the base class. What you find there will apply to all kinds of TextReader. It's a worthy investment of your time.

Comment: Your code already reads the response as string, you assign it to `richTextBox1.Text`.

Comment: Since you are working on a Windows forms application make use of the `WebBrowser` control. It'll be easy to find elements with that since you have access to DOM.

Comment: "Learning it yourself" is not an excuse for not familiarizing yourself with the documentation. Not to sound too much like "the old guy", but I learned .NET before there were any .NET books at all. But there _was_ MSDN documentation. It doesn't take examples to find the `ReadToEnd` method.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). You'll have much better results using that agility pack than you will parsing the html yourself using string functions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working on a Windows forms application make use of the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) control. It'll be easy to find elements with that since you have access to DOM.

Answer (score 0):

This is code snippet from a console app:

Here is the code where I get the Powerball homepage through a **HttpWebRequest**, and the using **RegEx** look for the jackpot, & read the current jackpot.

Hope this helps you.

```
  string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("PBHomePage")[0];
  HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
  webReq.ContentType = "text/html";
  Regex regex = new Regex("(<font size=\"6\" color=\"#FFFFFF\"><strong>\\$)(\\d+)(\\.*)(\\d*)(\\s+Million</strong></font>)");

  try
  {
    WebResponse response = webReq.GetResponse();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string webPage = reader.ReadToEnd();

    if (!regex.IsMatch(webPage)) { return null; }

    GroupCollection groups = regex.Match(webPage).Groups;

    StringBuilder strJackpot = new StringBuilder(groups[2].Value);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(groups[3].Value) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(groups[4].Value))
    {
      strJackpot.Append(groups[3].Value + groups[4].Value);
    }
    jackpot = double.Parse(strJackpot.ToString());
  }
  catch (WebException ex)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Error in getting Latest Jackpot");
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! I get ConfigurationManager does not exist in the current context error. :S

Comment: then add that to your using as well as add a reference too if needed... `Mesha Atkinson`

Comment: You can "not" use ConfigurationManager to get the url. Just use a plain string for url.